Refresh AWS Cognito Refresh Token Before Expiry
I'm currently facing an issue with AWS Cognito refresh tokens and would appreciate some guidance.
Problem:
I have an AWS Cognito setup where the refresh token is configured to expire after 30 days. The refresh token is used to generate new access tokens, and this process works fine for the entire duration of 30 days. However, once the refresh token expires, my protected resource calls result in 'Invalid token' or 'Token has expired' errors.
Requirement:
Is there a way to refresh the refresh token before its expiry time, similar to how we rotate the access token? Specifically, I want to understand how to:

Use the current access token or refresh token to refresh the refresh token within its expiry period.

Ensure that the refresh token is refreshed regularly to prevent expiration issues.


Additionally, I'd like to understand how platforms like Gmail manage tokens to last for long durations (e.g., months or years) without frequent manual re-authentication.
Context:

The refresh token has a 30-day expiry period.

Once expired, protected resource calls fail with 'Invalid token' or 'Token has expired' errors.


Questions:

Is there a built-in mechanism in AWS Cognito/Salesforce to refresh the refresh token within its expiry period?

How can I ensure seamless long-term authentication similar to platforms like Gmail?


Thank you for your help!
Attempts:

I have tried setting shorter expiry times for the access token, but the refresh token still expires after 30 days.

I have looked from Salesforce end also, we didn't find any absolute solution for this.



A good solution would be using a service like secrets manager on AWS. This allows you to store credentials securely including tokens. You can create a new secret in secrets manager to store your refresh token. Secrets manager has built in rotation feature which lets you call a lambda function on a set schedule. So you can set up a lambda which refreshes your refresh token after 29 days and stores it back into secrets manager. The process you have can then call secrets manager to fetch refresh token every time to make a call. Or you can call secrets manager to get new credentials in a "try catch/except" method where it only calls refresh token when you get the expired error.
If you don't want to use additional services you can just use try catch/except to generate new refresh token and store it when you get the token expired error.

In my case, I want something like sliding window. Refresh token validity should be less but each time I request new access token, the validity of refresh token should renew.
Other providers like Auth0 support this feature, not sure why Cognito does not!
